# Button activation on turning gear mechanism

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

Description of the mechanism: By turning a manual crank the mechanism activates a microswitch to activate an electronic circuit. The rotation is continuous and the microswitch must remain activated while rotating. When you stop turning the crank, the microswitch is deactivated, deactivating the electronic circuit.

I have seen many videos of examples of mechanisms and I can't imagine it :(

Comment: Is this homework? Can you think of any mechanism that will respond to rotational movement but could, for example, return to it's home position when the motion stops? [Edit] it into your question.

Comment: why does it have to be a mechanical switch? ... this may be an XY question ... asking for help with a perceived solution to a problem, instead of asking for help with the problem itself

Comment: centrifugal governor? Google it.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use pretty much the same idea as most mechanical governors did/do.

Let's start with a simplified version. We mount an arm to one side of the shaft, with a weight on the end of the arm:

[image]

When we spin the shaft, centripetal force on the weight will try to move it so it so the arm is sticking straight out radially from the shaft.

Assuming the microswitch is mounted the right distance from the shaft, when the weight swings out, it'll close the switch.

The problem, of course, is that it only contacts the switch once per revolution, so the switch will close momentarily, then open again for most of the revolution.

To fix that, we can start by making the weight in arc-shaped;

[image]

I've also added a little extra "arm" to stabilize the arc-shaped weight.

That lets the weight contact the switch for a quarter of a rotation (or so--depends on the exact size of arc you choose).

So to make it contact for the entire revolution, we add three more identical arms with identical weights, arranged around the shaft. You do typically need a little offset along the shaft between one and the next, so the weights won't hit each other when they move.

Oh, and we add a light spring to each to pull the arm/weight back in toward the shaft when we're not spinning it. It needs to be strong enough to keep the weight pulled in, so gravity won't pull the weight into contact with the switch, even when the arm is horizontal:

[image]

Of course, if the shaft is vertical, gravity isn't a factor. You still generally want at least a light spring to pull the arms in when the shaft isn't spinning though. With a vertical shaft, you can avoid the springs if you really want but it's usually more work than it's worth.